# Towards a different sort of set-identification

Tags: set-identification

I thought it might be fun for the holidays to try a different sort of [set-identification](/questions/tagged/set-identification).  Even though I know which set this is, it seemed like a pretty random set of bricks so I thought it might provide a brief challenge to the community.  Here it is:

[image: random LEGO pieces]

If this proves to be an actual challenge I'm happy to add hints later.

Comment: I'll be honest, it is random, but that painter's palette is a dead giveaway, as it only comes from 7 sets. From there it's only a matter of trimming down possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

## 40205 LEGO Holiday Little Elf Helpers. :)

Comment: That didn't take long.  :)

Comment: Do I get a Christmas cookie? Thanksgiving cookie is okay too. :)

Comment: I'll work out prizes for next time and some way to make it more challenging. :)

Comment: Ahhh... but I wanted a cookie!... (pouty face goes here)